The inverse of a non-multiplicative function in a set of arithmetic functions under Dirichlet product
I know how to find a Dirichlet inverse of multiplicative function  and $g(n)$=-$\frac{1}{f(1)}$$\sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d < n}}$$f(\frac{n}{d})g(d)$. But how about other arithmetic functions? Whether the reason why we just discuss the group of multiplicative functions with $f$ is non-zero is non-multiplicative functions do not maintain the structure needed for a well-defined Dirichlet inverse?

The inverse of an arithmetic function $f$ exists if and only if $f(1)\neq 0$. See also this post. You don't need that $f$ is multiplicative for this. Look up Theorem $2.8$ in the book by Tom M. Apostol.
